# Visio 2016 database diagram - how change data types and realign separator

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

I cannot find any window to list my entity's fields with their types. I found only way to set data type for specific field by typing on that data type field and write it manually (look at enclosed picture) i typed manually "string". I do not believe there is no window that types would be defined in list or whatever to choose rather than typing it manually. Moreover line which separates both field and data type columns - how to resize it so e.g "string" is not cut.

[Visio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJGVg.png)

Comment: There used to be an add-in built in to Visio that handled all that, but it has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape and then right-click and click

**Show Attribute Types**

The types can be edited by hand i.e. there are no set types to choose from. Select just the attribute part of the shape and press F2 to edit the text.

Comment: ok i see and is there possibility to also show optional fields (nullable fields) ?

Comment: I think that is up to you to show them however you want (maybe a different colour).